# How to translate jquery-ui datepicker localization options into coffee script?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, localization, coffeescript

I am new to both `javascript` and `coffeescript`. I am trying to initialize my datepicker to another language.

Given the following snippet in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization)...

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
});
```

If I do the following in my .js.coffee file in a Rails 4 app, it doesn't seem to be working.

```
jQuery ->
    $('#order_expected_delivery_date').datepicker
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        showAnim: 'slideDown'
        minDate: '+3D'
        maxDate: '+1M +3D'
        $.datepicker.regional[ "zh-CN" ]
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `$.datapicker.regional['zh-CN']`, you'll see something like this:

```
{
    closeText: ...,
    prevText: ...,
    ...
}
```

so the values in `$.datepicker.regional` are objects which hold a set of localized options for the datepicker. That means that your `datepicker` call really looks like this:

```
$('#order_expected_delivery_date').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    showAnim: 'slideDown'
    minDate: '+3D'
    maxDate: '+1M +3D'
    { closeText: '...', prevText: '...', ... }
```

and that is interpreted as **two** arguments to `datepicker`:

```
$('#order_expected_delivery_date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', ...
}, {
  closeText: '...', ...
})
```

and the localization options are ignored.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to merge the localization options into your options.

```
    options = $.extend({ }, $.datapicker.regional['zh-CN'], 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        showAnim: 'slideDown'
        minDate: '+3D'
        maxDate: '+1M +3D'
    )
    $('#order_expected_delivery_date').datepicker options
```

I use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) since you're already using jQuery. I also put the standard localized options *before* your options since `dateFormat` might be provided by the localized options and you want to use your own.

You could also use the [`option` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) like the example does:

```
$('#order_expected_delivery_date').datepicker 'option', $.datepicker.regional['zh-CN']
```

but that might overwrite your `dateFormat` so some care might be needed.